# JSP doPost getAtribute null value

Tags: jsp, post, get, attributes

I want to pass value to servlet but I keep get null value.

```
<jsp:useBean id="Helper" class="model.Registration" scope="request"/>
<form action="/Project/Registration" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" size="20" name="name" value="<%=Helper.getName()%>">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Registrationh2 = (Registration) request.getAttribute("Helper");
    if(h2!=null){
       System. out.println(h2.getName());
    }
    else
        System. out.println("NULL");        
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the scope, `jsp:useBean` will **not** work if you use `multipart/form-data` form encoding. This encoding is required to handle file uploads and the support to parse this encoding is *not* built in JSP/Servlet in such a transparent manner that `request.getParameter()` and consorts would return the desired value. The new Servlet 3.0 API has however support for this form encoding, but since you would need `request.getPart()` for this instead, this will not work with `jsp:useBean` as well.

As answered several times in related questions you posted before, you need [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) to parse a `multipart/form-data` request. You can however create a `Filter` which transparently parses and replaces the original `request` in case of `multipart/form-data` requests. You can find here a [blog article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/11/multipartfilter.html) about it, complete with code examples.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the Registration object is **request**. So it wont be available in the servlet which is a new request.
You can get the bean by setting in session. Or, make the scope to session.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to pass the name String from the Registration model. If that is the case you need fetch using the following code.

```
String registrationName = request.getParameter("name");
```

Also, remove the enctype as multipart. It is used when you are uploading any files from the client.